# Compile java from multiple directories

Tags: java, javac

I'm trying to compile multiple .java programs from different directories either on Windows, Mac, or Linux... e.g. cmd or terminal. It doesn't matter.

However, I'm sure that many of you are familiar with how Netbeans stores files in different folders. I have been putting different concepts into different folders, and now I want to run all of them.

For example, a chess program that I have looks sort of like this:

```
/Chess
    /build
        /classes
            /chess
                /Chess.class
            /color
                /colorHelper.class
            /game
                /Board.class
                /Game.class
                /GameManager.class
                /Player.class
            ... etc. (the rest of the directories with .class files)
    /build.xml
    /gameLog.txt
    /manifest.mf
    /nbproject
        ... (some xml and .properties files)
    /src
        /chess
            /Chess.java
        /color
            /ColorHelper.java
        /game
            /Board.java
            /Game.java
            /GameManager.java
            /Player.java
        ... etc. (the rest of the directories with .java files)
```

So, my question is, how can you use `javac *.java` (in `/src` probably) to compile all of the files (because otherwise I get a `cannot find symbol` error. Since I get a `file not found` when I run `javac *.java` in `src`, I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance,

Dylan

Comment: Would you consider in using a program like ANT or Maven or some other tool to compile your classes on the command line?

Comment: @JorgeCampos's right, but if you insist on not doing this, `javac $(find . -name '*.java')`

Comment: I've never used those because I've never had to... I could do some research on them. They would allow me to do what I want? (Of course I really could just run the program from Netbeans IDE ... or even put everything into a .jar, then run it with a .bat file ... but I want to learn from cmd or terminal).

Comment: As you are asking to do this on `Windows, Mac, or Linux` different plattaforms you will have to make a some bash/bat script for each or use one of the tools that i mentioned, it will work in any plattaform if they are proper installed.

Comment: right now it's in Mac terminal... in future it will be on windows cmd.exe as well as Ubuntu terminal. :)

Comment: haha. Sorry; for some reason I thought that was a question. (It's a little late...) Thanks, though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't compile in one go.Actually,your `src` directory doesn't contain any .java file,SO it won't be done in that way!

I am afraid that you'll have to do it by changing your path under `src` folder to do the same.

You'll have to perform for each `chess`,`color`,`game`,etc. directories to achieve the same.

So,change path at each run or go as advised in the comments to achieve compilation of all the java files.

**OR**

As proposed by David Ehrmann in your comment,you can do it by compiling in one go using `javac $(find . -name '*.java')`.

It will compile all .java files under your present directory(`src(.)`).

Comment: Ok! That sounds reasonable. Is `-name` just the name of the name of the current directory (int this case "src")?

Comment: @dyl-It is to specify name of the file you want to search!

Comment: Then what does the `.` do? Doesn't that specify the file to search?

Comment: Is that just the base dir or something?

Comment: @dyl- `.` is the way/syntax to represent current directory.It represents your `src` directory!

Comment: So, for this case is it `javac $(find . -chess '*.java'`?

Comment: I couldn't accept for 2 min! But it is my favorite. :)

Comment: No,it'll be javac $(find . -name '*.java')

Comment: What? I don't want to search the `/name` file, though because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @dyl-Man,name is an attribute,it searches for name,it's a behaviour which you need to specify.It's not for a source directory!!!

Comment: oh, attr got it... above you said `It is to specify name of the file you want to search` so I got confused

Comment: I told `to specify`---not that it itself specifies any directory!SORRY though,might be you mis-understood,or it might be my inability to make you understand in one go.

Comment: Works only in linux

Answer (score 0):

javac *.java compiles all the Java files within the current directory. In your case, since you have different hierarchy of folders based on the package, you cannot achieve this in one go. At best you can run the command javac *.java on each folder.

Comment: Don't you have to compile everything in one line? Or is that incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using an automated build system like maven or ant. It will allow you to build your project with a single command. It will even allow running unit tests, and packaging your application as a jar (or whatever package you prefer).

If you really don't want to use one of those you can still do it with a single (albeit lengthy) command. The *.java is just a wildcard in a file path. Its looking for any files in the current directory ending with .java. On linux you can try something like this `find -name "*.java" | xargs javac`. The first part is a find command that searches recursively for all files ending with .java. It this pipe's that list of files to xargs which adds them all as individual arguments to the java command.

That really isn't the best way. Again, try maven. Its pretty simple to set up for a basic project, your IDE usually has a feature to create a maven project for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

to compile more than one file having different package name in same folder use

```
javac -d . *.java
```

Comment: That doesn't work.